# How to write this lines as a List Comprehension?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension, spyder

I need help with this code, I don't have much knowledge in python

```
    i_averaged = []
    for i, ti in enumerate(t):
    if ti%time_intervall ==0:
        i_averaged.append(i)
    i_averaged.append(len(t)-1)
```

Comment: Show us the content of `t `...

Comment: To get a clear answer, you should first have a question. Please elaborate what help do you need: run the code, optimize, fix! Maybe add what effort have you made and what did you try?!

Comment: You need to fix the code indentation. Which lines are supposed to be inside the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the last line isn't in the loop, this can be written as

```
i_averaged = [i for i, ti in enumate(t) if ti % time_intervall == 0]
i_averages.append(len(t) - 1)
```